# Suricata rule for accessing SMB share?

Tags: detection, rules, smb, suricata

I've started to work with Suricata around a week ago and so far everything has been going surprisingly well. However, I am now trying to write my own rules and I tried to come up with a simple rule that throws an alert whenever any IP address tries to access my SMB share.

Taking a look at how the other SMB rules are written, I find this

`alert smb any any -> any any (msg:"SURICATA SMB internal parser error"; flow:to_client; app-layer-event:smb.internal_error; classtype:protocol-command-decode; sid:2225001; rev:1;)`

Following that pattern, my rule should like something like this:

`alert smb any any -> any any (msg:"Attempt to gain access to SMB Share"; flow:to_server; app-layer-event:smb.???; classtype:protocol-command-decode; sid:1234567; rev:1)`

However, I am not able to figure out (or find any information about) which app_layer_event to set. Can anybody help out here? It would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

hopefully, you've found an answer already, but for whoever may come here looking for that...

- I would say you don't need the `app-layer-event` field in the rule signature. That's more in case the SBM application layer detection protocol had thrown some specific event (cf. [[1]](https://suricata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rules/app-layer.html#app-layer-event)).
- Our documentation is lacking the section for `SMB` keywords (cf. [[2]](https://redmine.openinfosecfoundation.org/issues/3030)), but our Suricata-verify tool has a test with an example of `smb.share` usage [[3]](https://github.com/OISF/suricata-verify/blob/master/tests/smb2-03-rule/filedata.rules).

```
    alert smb any any -> any any (smb.share; content:"|5C 5C|10.0.0.12|5C|smb2"; sid:2;)
```

That content string means `smb.share: "\\\\10.0.0.12\\smb2"`.
If you check other Suricata-Verify tests, you'll find other examples of smb.share content:

```
    tests/smb2-05/test.yaml:22:        smb.share: "\\\\admin-pc\\c$"
    tests/smb2-05/test.yaml:87:        smb.share: "\\\\admin-pc\\c$"
    tests/smb2-07/test.yaml:69:        smb.share: "\\\\dc1\\ADMIN$"
    tests/smb3-01/test.yaml:27:        smb.share: "\\\\WS2016\\encrypted"
```

To understand how to translate such examples to what you see in the above rule, one can check the documentation for Payload keywords, like `content` cf. [[4]](https://suricata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rules/payload-keywords.html#content)).

Last but not least, Suricata community forum is more likely to get you timely answers, as we have not only active community members but also OISF team folks usually around: https://forum.suricata.io.

Sources:

[1](https://suricata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rules/app-layer.html#app-layer-event): App-layer-event keyword: https://suricata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rules/app-layer.html#app-layer-event

[2](https://redmine.openinfosecfoundation.org/issues/3030): Open ticket for adding SMB detection keyword to Suricata documentation: https://redmine.openinfosecfoundation.org/issues/3030

[3](https://github.com/OISF/suricata-verify/blob/master/tests/smb2-03-rule/filedata.rules): SMB rule in Suricata-verify with `smb.share`: https://github.com/OISF/suricata-verify/blob/master/tests/smb2-03-rule/filedata.rules

[4](https://suricata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rules/payload-keywords.html#content): Suricata rules - Payload keywords - content: https://suricata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rules/payload-keywords.html#content